# Consolidating data from different views into a single sql statement

Tags: oracle

I have 4 different view which will give the data in same format. My requirement is to write a single query which will combine data from all these four views with data from another table 'Table1' in such way that if that data in 'Table1' is already present in any of the four view(using some id) then i should not add it to the end result.

For eg: View1, View2, View3,View4 , Table1

My end result should be

> (View1+View2+View3+View4+(Table1-(View1+View2+View3+View4))

So the query which i have written is like below one

```
selet * from view1 union 
select * from view2 union 
select * from view3 union 
select * from view4 union 
select * from Table1 where Table1.Id Not in 
(select Id from view1 union 
select Id from view2 union 
select Id from view3 union 
select Id from view4 union)
```

Is there any better ways to frame this query which will improve the performance especially when there is a huge data

Comment: At the very least, replace the `union`s in the `not in` subquery with `union all`s - you don't care about uniqueness there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using distinct? :

```
select distinct(*) from (
select * from view1 union 
select * from view2 union 
select * from view3 union 
select * from view4 union 
select * from Table1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `not in` could be implemented as a `minus`. On a logical level you can achieve something like:

```
-- step 1
create or replace view v_basic
as
select *
from view1
union
select *
from view2
union
select *
from view3
union
select *
from view4;

-- step 2
create or replace view v_extension
as 
select id
from table1
minus
select id
from v_basic

-- step 3
select *
from v_basic
union
(select *
 from table1 t1
 where exists (select *
               from v_extension e1
               where e1.id = t1.id)
```

Since the union operator distinctly will get the a complete record perhaps you will not have to bother whether an id appears twice. So if the id attribute is the main attribute that tells you whether a record should be retrieved from table1 then you can approach the problem as suggested in then answer. If a whole record holds the distinctive data then you could merge all queries with `union` operator. In that case =>

```
select *
from v_basic
union
select *
from table1
```

... should be enough